# How to put video using vlcj in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, api

My problem is that I don't know how to put video using vlcj in java swing. The proper way step by step. I am having trouble inserting video in my project.

I do having an problem inserting video in my project. I tried a lot of codes that I had research in the internet. I followed the step by inserting vlcj.jar in my code. But when I try to copy and paste some of codes in stacksoverflow there are some missing methods that my IDE cannot recognize even I import jars needed. My IDE is intelliJ. Please help me it's my project ;(.

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class VLCPlayer extends JPanel {
    public VLCPlayer(){
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);
        mediaPlayer.playMedia(String with the name of the file);
    }
}
```

this is just sample I don't know what is the correct code in order to run it properly please help me.

The Actual result I want to do is that a video only running on a JFrame thats all. Please help me thanks anyway :)

Comment: There are complete step-by-step tutorials linked on the vlcj project page at Github, and many, many sample applications in the src/test directory. Have you tried those?

Comment: what code should I use there? I am trying some codes there but I don't know exactly what code should I use in order to display video in my project